# How to make sure that mongodb altas connection first connects then run the Nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When i hit 10 API in my Nodejs app out of those 10 i got error from one API however that one API is random i don't know which API will get that error after searching the error on internet i found that its the problem with my atlas connection so How to make sure that mongodb altas connection first connects then run the Nodejs app? i am using "mongoose" package for making connection...

```
Error:
{"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out","reason":{"errorType":"MongoServerSelectionError","errorMessage":"connection timed out","reason":{"type":"ReplicaSetNoPrimary","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":"atlas-uyfrl7-shard-0","maxElectionId":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"commonWireVersion":0,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null},"stack":\["MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out","    at Timeout.\_onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/agenda/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:292:38)","    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)","    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)"\]},"promise":{},"stack":\["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out","    at process.\<anonymous\> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1189:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)","    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)","    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)","    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)"\]}
\[ERROR\] \[1688974911770\] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success response. Http response code: 400.
RequestId: 2522508f-65d2-4e3c-a8f6-d90cb37b0a98 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 128
Runtime.ExitError
```

Index.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import { UserRoute } from './src/apis/UserRoute.js';
import { MongoDBConnection } from './src/database/db.js';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();
app.use(compression());

MongoDBConnection();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(UserRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res) =\> {
res.send('Hello World');
})

app.listen(port, () =\> {
console.log('Server is running on port ' + port);
})
```

db.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

export const MongoDBConnection = async () =\> {
try {
await mongoose.connect('mymongourlhere')
console.log('Connected to database');
} catch (err) {
console.log('Error connecting to database: ' + err);
}
};
```